# How to write a SQL query to find the percentage using 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the percentage of users who only visited a mobile and the percentage of users that were on both mobile/web.

Table 1: User

```
user_id | page 
6684    | home_page
```

Table 2: MobileData​

```
user_id | page
1210    | page_6_mobile
```

Table 3: WebData​

```
user_id | page
129     | page_1_web
```

Comment: Welkom on stackoverflow.. i advice you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

To find all the users:

```
SELECT user_id FROM User
```

To find all the users who have been on mobile:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM MobileData
```

We use `DISTINCT` so that we only get one row for each user.

To find all the users who have been on both mobile and web:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id
FROM User u
JOIN MobileData m ON m.user_id = u.user_id
JOIN WebData w ON w.user_id = u.user_id;
```

Now we just need to count all the results and compute the percentages:

```
SELECT total_users,
       mobile_users / total_users * 100 AS percent_mobile,
       mobile_and_web_users / total_users * 100 AS percent_both
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_users,
             (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM MobileData) AS mobile_users,
             (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_id)
              FROM User u
              JOIN MobileData m ON m.user_id = u.user_id
              JOIN WebData w ON w.user_id = u.user_id) AS mobile_and_web_users
      FROM User) u
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e126c/18)

**Update**

Here is a much cleaner version of the query. It uses a `LEFT JOIN` from `User` to `MobileData` to find all users who have been on mobile (while retaining the entire list of users). Then it uses another `LEFT JOIN` from `MobileData` to `WebData` to find users who have been on mobile and web. By doing this we can simplify the counting to a neat `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)` on each table:

```
SELECT total_users,
       mobile_users / total_users * 100 AS percent_mobile,
       mobile_and_web_users / total_users * 100 AS percent_both
FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_id) AS total_users,
             COUNT(DISTINCT m.user_id) AS mobile_users,
             COUNT(DISTINCT w.user_id) AS mobile_and_web_users
      FROM User u
      LEFT JOIN MobileData m ON m.user_id = u.user_id
      LEFT JOIN WebData w ON w.user_id = m.user_id) u
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e126c/24)

Comment: @MacUnited Apologies, I realised I had an error in my query, I had given you mobile **or** web users instead of mobile **and** web users. I've updated the answer.